# csproj.nuget files are not automatically created for NET projects

Tags: c#, .net-core

The following errors appear when building some of the NET projects with Visual Studio 2022 17.7.6:

```
12>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.403\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop\targets\Microsoft.WinFX.targets(407,7): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "D:\Git\CodeBase\Source\..\..\Artifacts\CodeBase11\Intermediate\\CodeBase.Controls.csproj.nuget.g.props" because it was not found.

12>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.403\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop\targets\Microsoft.WinFX.targets(407,7): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "D:\Git\CodeBase\Source\..\..\Artifacts\CodeBase11\Intermediate\\CodeBase.Controls.csproj.nuget.g.targets" because it was not found.

12>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.403\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop\targets\Microsoft.WinFX.targets(407,7): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "D:\Git\CodeBase\Source\..\..\Artifacts\CodeBase11\Intermediate\\CodeBase.Controls.csproj.nuget.dgspec.json" because it was not found.
```

To solve the issue, I have to manually run the following command in the Package manager console:
`nuget restore "D:\Git\CodeBase\Source\CodeBase.Controls\CodeBase.Controls.csproj"`

Project file:

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <SignAssembly>True</SignAssembly>
    <AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>..\CodeBase.snk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <Platforms>x64</Platforms>  
    <IntermediateOutputPath>$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\$(MSBuildProjectName)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
    <OutputPath>$(BaseOutputPath)CodeBase\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\CodeBase\</OutputPath>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Effects\Shaders\ContrastAdjustShader.ps" />
    <None Remove="Effects\Shaders\GreyscaleShader.ps" />
    <None Remove="Effects\Shaders\RedScaleShader.ps" />
  </ItemGroup> 
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CodeBase.Core\CodeBase.Core.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CodeBase.IO.Data\CodeBase.IO.Data.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CodeBase.IO\CodeBase.IO.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CodeBase.LinearAlgebra\CodeBase.LinearAlgebra.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <InternalsVisibleTo Include="CodeBase.Common, PublicKey=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" />
    <InternalsVisibleTo Include="CodeBase.Graphics, PublicKey=0649338b6f22d7aa56629b39a119e3e32c77f1bed16e471fc32a9e89e2d471e275a335b4be8244d511af12d6b8b80c193d1bbe704ebfd377c7f64a3ca085298084edae612282318909d54b24b2aa87d835f15c0f3cbbf5eb81c4ec6a963bce3356c54cd668eb7da5763bdcce40c39f66dd83acec098a66ff80161a02b20eeb0d634bb37c54cdf4176a57de840fc80135a1adfaf9e09ad541b23f19d6f915477c8d27282f2b10f5a02596d91be6c41d6bc17213790cd7f401805640213205e1b8628e3092b2a7506f2de6815335674ddeb236f79a68a74fb57ecf01d3c7861afa4dd528e5d165a32557d50c5b5a204aa6fb9a6e93251209bf4ac017bdc798212312e9e69f4d117b4773e12f40ea8ac4e383f675cd31951f80329ba0f11be631d90e1872281a6a73e73b921e81e94cf9576fe4862d8d5158750db442143bb3e7534f6b8d8aacaedb447c66310439c4ec1101395a7f1384e321af77cb6f310ba0b48efec38c40778cbfb9e87ecee546562a5fc549affe34b95a010fd0d7bd7c566188b4a0bc0e804dd9659de3d56dbbb9629938103d56309eaa5881f996e038b387fc003b8f4da2776a014744bdb3b9fa0524d82b170faf8260432abefd81d3a4e5853f85c7cfdd22610f0713f946078f315c33cdc1811688ce7bec" />
    <InternalsVisibleTo Include="CodeBase.Viewer, PublicKey=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" />
    <InternalsVisibleTo Include="CodeBase.WindowsShellExtensions, PublicKey=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" />
    <InternalsVisibleTo Include="CodeBase.Home, PublicKey=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" />
    <InternalsVisibleTo Include="CodeBase.Workspace, PublicKey=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" />
    <InternalsVisibleTo Include="CodeBase.Library, PublicKey=0649338b6f22d7aa56629b39a119e3e32c77f1bed16e471fc32a9e89e2d471e275a335b4be8244d511af12d6b8b80c193d1bbe704ebfd377c7f64a3ca085298084edae612282318909d54b24b2aa87d835f15c0f3cbbf5eb81c4ec6a963bce3356c54cd668eb7da5763bdcce40c39f66dd83acec098a66ff80161a02b20eeb0d634bb37c54cdf4176a57de840fc80135a1adfaf9e09ad541b23f19d6f915477c8d27282f2b10f5a02596d91be6c41d6bc17213790cd7f401805640213205e1b8628e3092b2a7506f2de6815335674ddeb236f79a68a74fb57ecf01d3c7861afa4dd528e5d165a32557d50c5b5a204aa6fb9a6e93251209bf4ac017bdc798212312e9e69f4d117b4773e12f40ea8ac4e383f675cd31951f80329ba0f11be631d90e1872281a6a73e73b921e81e94cf9576fe4862d8d5158750db442143bb3e7534f6b8d8aacaedb447c66310439c4ec1101395a7f1384e321af77cb6f310ba0b48efec38c40778cbfb9e87ecee546562a5fc549affe34b95a010fd0d7bd7c566188b4a0bc0e804dd9659de3d56dbbb9629938103d56309eaa5881f996e038b387fc003b8f4da2776a014744bdb3b9fa0524d82b170faf8260432abefd81d3a4e5853f85c7cfdd22610f0713f946078f315c33cdc1811688ce7bec" />
    <InternalsVisibleTo Include="CodeBase, PublicKey=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" />
  </ItemGroup>
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AvalonEdit" Version="6.3.0.90" />
    <PackageReference Include="Dirkster.AvalonDock" Version="4.20.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="DynamicLanguageRuntime" Version="1.3.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Extended.Wpf.Toolkit" Version="4.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="LiveCharts" Version="0.9.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="LiveCharts.Wpf" Version="0.9.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="MahApps.Metro" Version="2.4.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf" Version="1.1.39" />
    <PackageReference Include="WpfAnalyzers" Version="4.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="ZetaLongPaths.NetStandard" Version="1.0.0.35" />
  </ItemGroup>
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Effects\Shaders\ContrastAdjustShader.ps" />
    <Resource Include="Effects\Shaders\GreyscaleShader.ps" />
    <Resource Include="Effects\Shaders\RedScaleShader.ps" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Does anyone know how to create these files automatically with Visual Studio?

Comment: Show us your `.csproj` file. What version of VS are you using?

Comment: I have added the proj file and I use Visual Studio 2022 17.7.6.

Comment: Show us your `CodeBase.props` file, and any relevant `Directory.Build.props` file(s) too.

Comment: Would I be correct in assuming this is an old WPF project that was updated to target .NET 6.0?

Comment: Yes we are in the progress of migrating from .NET framework 4.8 to NET 6.0

Comment: I have added the props files (without all the links to the third party libraries).

Comment: Your `.csproj` (and `.props`) files are the "old-style" (pre-"SDK-style") which I suspect is causing all these problems. You should create a brand new empty WPF+.NET 7 project (and why target .NET 6.0 when the new LTSC build of .NET 8.0 is out already?) and add files back.

Comment: I used the recommended way to migrate csproj files based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-overview . What do you mean that the csproj file is the "old-style" ? (it is using <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"> which allows to get rid of AssemblyInfo.cs and all the links to the source file)

Comment: It's old-style because your `.csproj` is completely littered with redundant and obsolete MSBuild properties, like `VCAnalyzeOnlyAllowed` and `<CodeAnalysisRuleSet>` (both supplanted by `.editorconfig`, etc) - and you have `<Reference` elements for DLLs that are already referenced via `<PackageReference />`.

Comment: `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>` <-- You're sure this plays-nice with WPF?

Comment: Well it run fine in other projects so I'm tempted to think so.

Comment: I will try to clean the csproj files though and see if it helps.

Comment: I have removed the <Reference> and 
<UseWindowsForms> but it didn't solve the issue.
Recreating the project from scratch is a much bigger task but I think that I'm getting desperate enough to try it.

Comment: @Dai I have created the project from scratch using the visual studio template and it didn't solve the issue (I have updated the description)